# Restoring a new iPhone via iCloud post-setup?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, wifi, restore

I am trying to restore my new iPhone with the data from my old iPhone via iCloud. I have tried to follow [this tutorial](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4859), but unfortunately I cannot connect to wifi during the setup process (my wifi requires me to activate each device via safari/some other mobile browser).

Is there any way to restore my old data (i.e. photos, texts, etc.) after the setup process?

Comment: Is restoring through iTunes an option? Do you still have the old phone around that you could backup to iTunes and then restore to the new iPhone?

Comment: Unfortunately the old iPhone is dead, and I only backed up to iCloud

Comment: I am going out on a limb to say that you "found" a significant (IMO) loop hole in the iCloud restoration process. As I am sure you are well aware, normally, when a user connects to a wifi, Apple pings a web page on their site. If it fails to connect, it will pull up an in-app browser so you cannot log in. But it sounds like that in-app browser is absent during iCloud setup.

Answer (score 1):

Since this appears to be a defect in Apple's software with no non-hacky solution, I thought I would share how I worked around this issue to achieve semi-restoration:

- **Photos**: I first imported my photos from my iCloud photostream to iPhoto using [this tutorial](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2712?viewlocale=en_US). Then I went to `iTunes --> iPhone --> Photos` and checked "Sync Photos from iPhoto." Further, oddly enough, after linking iCloud to my iPhone again post-setup, a photo stream was synced with my phone, albeit missing a lot of photos. But iPhoto was able to load them all, so it didn't really matter.
- **Contacts**: Luckily I had my contacts already synced with my Mac Contacts app. So to add my existing contacts all I had to do was go to `iTunes --> iPhone --> Info` and check "Sync Contacts."
- **Calendar**: I use Google calendar, so this was as simple as setting up my email again. However, even if you relied on your iPhone calendar, I believe this issue can be resolved by going to `iTunes --> iPhone --> Info` and selecting "Sync Calendar."
- **Notes**: Once I linked my iCloud to my phone post-setup, these notes automatically synced from the Notes Mac app.

What I was unable to sync:

- Messages. Unfortunate but not really that important.
- Applications. But these can easily be re-downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to restore a iCloud backup after my phone had a meltdown and I had to erase it and start again.  The only WiFi network I had was in a hotel room which meant I had to enter my room number and name to register.  I realised it worked off MAC addresses so I

- did a basic phone start up to and registered on the wifi
- erased the phone again
- restarted the phone and restored from backup